# Will XMPP work in a NAT environment?

Tags: session, xmpp, protocols, nat, endpoint

An XMMP server sends push notifications to a client behind a NAT using a public endpoint( IP + Port) supplied by NAT to client. But how long this endpoint is assigned to this specific client by NAT, what will happen if NAT assigns same endpoint to another client ? How this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP uses a standard TCP connection. NATs will keep the association for as long as the connection is alive (unless they are horribly broken).

**Update:** The last part of my statement could have been expanded a bit. Horribly broken NAT implementations *do* exist. Generally these are a small percentage, but many (most?) popular XMPP clients do ensure they send some kind of keepalive over idle connections.

There are three kinds of keepalive you can use I'll list them here in order of bandwidth/processing requirements:

TCP keepalives are a good lightweight option, especially as once they are enabled, they are automatically handled by the OS. How to enable them will depend on your language and framework, but at the lowest level, you need to enable the `SO_KEEPALIVE` option on the socket.

There are two problems with TCP keepalives. One is that you can't control them from your application (unless you write platform-specific code). The second problem is that some NAT implementations are *so* broken that they will ignore TCP keepalives too! But you're hopefully down to a very small percentage now.

So another option is [whitespace keepalives](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-silence-dead). Since these involve data going across the stream, you should be safe from even the broken NATs that ignore keepalives.

Whitespace keepalives simply involve sending the space character (' ') across the XMPP stream at any time it is idle. XML and XMPP allow unlimited whitespace between elements, and it is simply ignored by the recipient.

Finally, you can use fully-fledged [XMPP pings (XEP-0199)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html). These involve ending an actual `<iq/>` 'get' stanza to the server, which then must reply. This ensures data flows in both directions, and should make even the most broken NAT implementations keep your connection alive.

Ok, I should mention that there is an even worse class of NAT. I have seen NATs that will simply 'forget' about your mapping for a range of reasons, including their mapping table being full, or just after a timer. There is nothing you can do to work around these, they don't work with any long-lived TCP connections. The best you could probably do at that point is use [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/bosh/) (essentially XMPP over HTTP).

**Conclusion:** If you are concerned that your application may run behind some of these devices, I suggest something like the following algorithm (exact times may be tweaked, but I recommend these as minimum values):

- If you have not sent any data for 60s, send a single space character.
- If you have not received any data for 120s, send an XMPP ping to your server.
- If the server doesn't reply to the ping within a reasonable amount of time, reconnect.

Because the behaviour of broken NAT devices is beyond any standard protocol specification, it is naturally impossible to devise a perfect solution that will work with all of them, all of the time. You just have to accept that these are a small minority, and none of this matters for working NAT devices (though there are other kinds of network breakages that may make regular keepalives/pings a good idea, depending on the needs of your application).

Comment: This is wrong. Nats drop the mapping entry After some idle Time. Typically After 15 to 45min.

Comment: @tobias *Some* will, yes. As I said, they are horribly broken. If you think this statement is incorrect, please name the RFC that says it isn't. Then you can downvote my answer :)

Comment: @tobias: I've updated my answer with more detail covering different levels of brokenness, and how to work around them.

Comment: Perhaps mention XEP-0198 as well.  Some NATs kill your connection after some time, and it's nice to be able to reconnect quickly and know what you've missed.

Comment: Now your answer is more complete. But the reason for doing this is not because the NAT is broken. There are RFCs which state that dropping a TCP / UDP mapping state after some idle time. RFC4787 recommends dropping for UDP after 5 min. RFC5382 recommends dropping of TCP mapping entry after 2hours and 4 min.

Comment: @tobias: You win. This is crazy - from RFC5382: "When a NAT abandons a live connection, for example due to a timeout expiring, the NAT MAY either send TCP RST packets to the endpoints or MAY silently abandon the connection.". I'm speechless.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is sending keep alive messages to maintain the NAT entry. XMPP whitespace is typically used. Send it eg every Ten minutes to preserve reachability of the nated client.

You have to keep in mind that NAT is no standardized technique. Thus there are different implementations. The provided RFCs in the comment above is from the BEHAVE working group.

Comment: Instead of using XMPP whitespace. XMPP pings (XEP-0199) should be used.

Comment: I am very unsure on that. I think ping/pong is used for Dead Peer Detection.

Comment: XMPP Ping can serve same purpose as a whitespace: To keep the TCP connection active and there preventing NAT timeouts. We do this in (a)Smack.

Comment: Yes if the DPD interval is in the range of the required keep-alive interval. I cant find the source but I wrote in the mailing list that Whitespace was targeting keepalive and ping targets DPD. But you are right that XMPP ping solves both!